# Pasring JSON objects that aren't going to be in every record

Tags: python, json, twitter

I've got some data I've acquired from the Twitter Streaming API that I'm trying to  parse using python.  I've been successful doing this for the most part when parsing out objects that are in ALL records.  However, when trying to parse objects that are not be in every record, such as `['coordinates']` or  `['entities']['hashtags']` I run into an error.

```
import json
import sys

def main():

    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()

        data = ''

        try:
            data = json.loads(line)
        except ValueError as detail:
            continue

        if not (isinstance(data, dict)):
            ## not a dictionary, skip
            pass
        elif 'delete' in data:
            ## a delete element, skip for now.
            pass
        elif 'user' not in data:
            ## bizarre userless edge case
            pass
        else:
            print "\t".join([
            data['created_at'],
            data['user']['screen_name'],
            data['user']['id_str'],
            data['user']['lang'],
            data['text'],
            data['source']
            ]).encode('utf-8')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `data['coordinates']`, you could use `data.get('coordinates')`.

Using `dict.get(key)` will return `None` if the key isn't in the dictionary, rather than raising a `KeyError`.

Comment: I tried `data.get('coordinates')` and I get the following error: `TypeError: sequence item 6: expected string or Unicode, NoneType found`